# Producer Consumer Pattern using TPL & tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

We have a standard producer consumer implementation with a BlockingCollection being used with tasks.

The Consumption of the items is done using GetConsumingEnumerable() on the blocking collection and each task is then executed using RunSynchronously() on the consumers thread.

This works fine for us, but now some of the tasks instead of being quite short lived will be speaking to back end web services.

So the question is, is it acceptable for the task which performs a long running activity to be done in this way, or is this going to consume more resources and the loop which takes from the blockcollection needs adjusting in someway to use continuations instead?  If it weren't in the loop then i'd always be using continuations for these sorts of operations.

Current code looks like

```
foreach(var task in _Queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    if (!task.IsCanceled)
    {
        task.RunSynchronously();
    }
}
```

Given the platforms we are also targeting, usage of async await is out of the question.

Comment: It really sounds like you're trying to implement `async`. Difficult. Would the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` package help? It extends `async` / `await` support to .NET 4.0, Silverlight 4/5, and Windows Phone 7.5/8.0.

Comment: What's the difference between that and Async Targeting Pack?

Comment: It hasn't been stated officially AFAIK, but I expect `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` to replace the Async Targeting Pack in the near future. It supports more platforms but is still in a beta stage at the moment.

Comment: Unfortunately the code also runs on iOS & Android devices for which support for async is not available until Q1 next year.